# onLongClick should only happen if condition is true

Tags: android, imageview, onlongclicklistener

This is a part of my code:

```
        if(user.getUserID().equals(thisLike.getUserID())) {
            Log.i("On MARKER click", "Equal User ID!");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.longpress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            markerImage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("On MARKER click", "onLongClick HAPPENS!");
                    if(user.getUserID().equals(thisLike.getUserID())) {
                        Log.i("On MARKER click", "Equal User ID!");
                        openContextMenu(markerImage);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        Log.i("On MARKER click", "Not equal User ID!!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.i("On MARKER click", "F...off!");
            return false;
        }
```

It describes some behavior within `onMarkerClick` on a `GoogleMap`  `Marker`.

What I want to happen is for the `ContextMenu` to open ONLY when `user.getUserID()` is equal to `thisLike.getUserID()`

I have tried adding `markerImage.setOnLongClickListener(null);` on both else statements. Did not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this solution is not perfect... I've added the if-check to `onCreateContextMenu` like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if(user.getUserID().equals(thisLike.getUserID())) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Image options");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu_image, menu);
    }
}
```

It is finally respecting the if-check, but I would still like to know why the if-check for `onLongClick` isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following logic.

```
if (false){
    setOnLongClickListener(null)
    } else{
    // Implement your own listener
    }
```